# Image from Image Picker in Null for the First Time after Permission

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-image, flutter-image-picker

I'm using `image_picker`, and I've noticed something weird on Android, that is when I pick an image for the first time (Right after giving permission to storage), it returns null.

Here's my function for picking image. Here are the steps that is follows;

1. Check for `Permission.status`
2. If the status is granted, the pick image,
3. Else if the status is permanently denied then show a dialog to open
   settings.
4. If permission is not permanently denied then request permission.

```
Future<File?> pickImage(
      {ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.gallery}) async {
    XFile? pickedFile;

    const permission = Permission.storage;

    final PermissionStatus status = await permission.status;
    print("status $status");
    if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
      pickedFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);

      log(pickedFile?.path ?? "No File");
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        log(File(pickedFile.path).path ?? "No File");
        return File(pickedFile.path);
      }
    } else if (status == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      final requestedStatus = await permission.request();
      if (requestedStatus == PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
        getErrorDialog(
            GeneralError(
                title: 'Permission Denied',
                message: 'Please provide Storage Permissions'),
            buttonText: 'Open Settings', onPressed: () async {
          await openAppSettings();
          Get.back();
        });
      } else if (requestedStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        await pickImage();
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
```

```
V/AudioManager( 5753): playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
I/flutter ( 5753): status PermissionStatus.denied
W/InputMethodManager( 5753): startInputReason = 1
I/flutter ( 5753): status PermissionStatus.granted
I/SurfaceView( 5753): delay destroy surface control
I/SurfaceView( 5753): need destroy surface control
D/HwGalleryCacheManagerImpl( 5753): mIsEffect:false
I/flutter ( 5753): null
I/flutter ( 5753): file
[log] Inside Image Service
[log] /data/user/0/com.knkit.dis_customer/cache/a5b3b9b1-14f6-4c3d-af4e-054c3133aca1/IMG-20230513-WA0006.jpg
[log] /data/user/0/com.knkit.dis_customer/cache/a5b3b9b1-14f6-4c3d-af4e-054c3133aca1/IMG-20230513-WA0006.jpg
I/ViewRootImpl( 5753): jank_removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
W/InputMethodManager( 5753): startInputReason = 1
```

When I tried to print the `pickedFile!.path`, it did print the path to the picked file, but my function `pickImage` still returned `null`, which I have called inside controller.

I'm wondering if there is some problem in my logic, but the same code works correctly for the ios simulator.

Comment: Could you please share **log**?

Comment: as per the log, it returns the file path too.

Comment: I does print the file path intsie this function, but in the controller, where i'm calling this function `null` is reutrned.

Comment: If this function is return null then how is possible to print the path in your controller where you call this function?

Comment: Found the cause of the problem. It's weird that it's a logical error because the same code worked well on the ios simulator. Inside the `status == PermissionStatus.denied` -> `status == PermissionStatus.granted` I was recalling the `pickImge` function, and I had to return it as well, without returning from there, the code moves to `return null` after successfully picking the image.

Comment: @DevPankajPatel The path that is shown in logs was printed inside the function, not inside the controller.

Comment: Need to relace this snippet ` pickedFile = await _imagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);

      log(pickedFile?.path ?? "No File");
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        log(File(pickedFile.path).path ?? "No File");
        return File(pickedFile.path);
      }` when you are calling function in side function `await pickImage();`;

Comment: Just by `return await pickImage();` resolved the issue on android, but I'm confused as why did this code gave correct output on ios simulator!

Comment: Okay. but recursion in function is not good for small function/logic it's good for complex logic.